# PrimeFaces CellEditEvent - Method not found error

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

> [ERROR   ] An exception occurred
>   javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /partner/index.xhtml at line 44 and column 78 action="#{PartnerEdit.cellRowEdit()}": Method not found: com.ibm.ic.partner.view.PartnerEdit@3302e49a.cellRowEdit()

```
<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{PartnerEdit.cellRowEdit()}" />
```

```
@ManagedBean(name="PartnerEdit")

@ViewScoped
public class PartnerEdit implements Serializable {

public void cellRowEdit(CellEditEvent event){       
        System.out.println(event.getNewValue());        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#{PartnerEdit.cellRowEdit()}
```

References a method without any parameter.
As your method actually has a parameter, you need to reference it without braces:

```
#{PartnerEdit.cellRowEdit}
```